# migrating wordpress site to dev url

Tags: wordpress

I'm sure this must be simple. I'm moving a wordpress site from one server to another. as a result i've set up a sub domain for it as a test url and copied the files over.

However all I get now is blank pages.

http://nicsroadtorecovery.anytimeafter9.co.uk/

can anyone give me any clues

thanks

Answer (score 1):

My personal workflow for migrating a development into a live site looks like:

1. Download the whole WordPress folder from your development system
2. Export used database (suggesting [MySQL dumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/))
3. Upload the WordPress files again on your live system
4. Import database dump (with MySQL dumper again)
5. Update wp-config.php with your new database settings (server, database, user, password)
6. Finally: use the mighty **[Database Search & Replace Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)** like this: replace: "sandbox.mysite.com" with "mysite.com" and run!

That's how my WordPress site migration workflow runs and I really love the Database Search & Replace Script which updates the link structure even within used widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You should also create a demo database, and thus you have to update your settings in wp-config.php.

First step is to copy all of your files from the production server in the developer server.
Second step export the production database and import it in the developer server.
Third step, you have to run the following SQL:

```
UPDATE {prefix}_options SET option_value = 'ENTER_HERE_YOUR_DEVELOPER_SITE_URL' WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl', 'home');
```

Fourth step, chenge the `wp_config.php` options, to meet the developer server MySQL information.

**NOTE:** The `{prefix}` is the tables prefix you have use for your installation.
**NOTE:** The `ENTER_HERE_YOUR_DEVELOPER_SITE_URL` is the url of the home page in your developer installation

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I'd already done most of it bar the update query. however still a blank site

Comment: If you have follow this procudure, then is should work. This ia the standard migration procedure I am following for any project requiring migration. If still blank page, this mean, that somewhere is a bug. Check your server error log, and or enable php error reporting.

Comment: If you got the correct answer please upvode and/or check this answer as correct. This way you help other StackOverflow member to save time. :)